# C# .NET CORE Abrir PDF en una nueva pestaña

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Hola lo que quiero es abrir una nueva pestaña para mostrar un pdf desde ajax con el metodo POST y no he conseguido el resultado deseado

En mi controlador tengo esto ya intente con FileContentResult y File

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> GenerarReporte(Guid id, ReporteMovimientoInventarioModel.Filtros filtros)
{
    if (id == App.Reportes.Inventario.MovimientoInventario.Id)
    {
        var filtro =  filtros;
        var reporte = new Reportes.Inventario.MovimientoInventario(filtro, _context, _webHostEnvironment);
        //return new FileContentResult((await reporte.CrearReporteAsync()).GetByteArray(), "application/pdf");
        return File((await reporte.CrearReporteAsync()).GetByteArray(), "application/pdf", "A.PDF");
        //return (await reporte.CrearReporteAsync()).GetByteArray();
    }

    throw new Exception("");
}
```

y en javascript tengo esto

```
$.ajax({

                url: '@Url.Action("GenerarReporte", "Reporte")',
                data: {
                    id : "5205502C-D59A-4B43-80DD-1E63B4302779",
                    filtros : { Material : "aa"}
                },
                type: "POST",
                success: function(f) {
                    
                    var file = new Blob([f], { type: 'application/pdf' });
                    var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    console.log(file)
                    window.open(fileURL); 
                },

                error: function(xhr, status) {

                    let msg;

                    if (xhr.responseJSON != undefined && xhr.responseJSON != null) {
                        msg = xhr.responseJSON.error;
                    } else {
                        msg = xhr.responseText == "" || xhr.responseText == null ? xhr.statusText : xhr.responseText;
                    }

                    MensajeUtil.Error(msg);
                },

                complete: function(xhr, status) {

                }
            });
```

Y me abre otra ventana pero con el pdf vacio :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Necesariamente tiene que ser con ajax??

Comment: Suficiente con un `href` y un `target_blank` que apunten a la URL de donde se generará el PDF y ya.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que estoy enviando con POST y no con GET por eso no puedo hacer lo de href y otra cosa me abre el pdf en blanco pero si le doy recargar si se ve